# gcloud command to save datastore kind to google storage

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Looking for gcloud command to save the google cloud datastore entities to google cloud storage.Right now I'm manually doing all the operations would like to see if this can be done through shell commands as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a command to export named kinds to GCS:

`gcloud beta datastore export --kinds="KIND1, KIND2" --namespaces="NAMESPACE1, NAMESPACE2" gs://${BUCKET}`

Typically, you would run:

`gcloud beta datastore export --kinds="foo" --namespaces="(default)" gs://my-gcs-bucket/datastore_export/2017-11-09_12_00`

The documentation can be found here:
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities

And then the exported data can then be loaded into BigQuery.

If you don't want to load the data into BigQuery, the format isn't documented, but here are some references for how to read the entities from the exported LevelDB files:

http://varunpant.com/posts/read-gae-admin-backups-fromleveldb-format-and-export-gae-entities-using-bulkloader

http://gbayer.com/big-data/app-engine-datastore-how-to-efficiently-export-your-data/